# Kentico 6 Migration - Forcing Installer

Tags: asp.net, migration, kentico

I've just migrated over all of the files, and database for one of our Kentico sites, and it's now forcing me to re-run the installer, and I can't work out any way to bypass this.

I'm assuming something (a file, a database param) is missing to say the installer has already been run.

How can I prevent the re-run after a copy?

Answer (score 1):

That's usually caused by missing connection string in the web.config. The connection string must have a name `CMSConnectionString`.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was the default database schema that caused it.